# Why does MTP work on one machine, but not another?

Tags: windows-xp, usb, mp3, mtp

I have two Dell computers, a laptop and a desktop. I reinstalled Windows XP home on both, from the same CD. Then I installed Service pack 3 and ran windows update. When I connect my Creative Zen media player to the desktop, the MTP software that is part of XP recognizes it, and I can copy file to and from it using Windows Explorer. But when I connect the same player with the same cable to the laptop, I can see it in Windows Explorer, but none of the folders that are visible via the desktop are available, and I can't copy anything to or from it. How can I get this working on the laptop?

Comment: Probably not the problem, but I noticed my Zen doesn't like USB hubs, and usually only works properly when connected directly to a port in the back of the PC.

Comment: The Zen is connected directly with no hub in both cases. Thanks for the tip, but I have never needed to use a hub.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Zen and have experienced nothing but trouble using anything other than their software. I don't like using it, as dragging and dropping files is so much easier. By using their software I haven't had any problems with songs or videos not being the right format, noy playing, etc. Also check out the support page:
http://support.creative.com/Products/ProductDetails.aspx?catID=213&CatName=MP3+Players&subCatID=214&subCatName=ZEN&prodID=16999&prodName=ZEN
It could just be a firmware thing.

Update: I found another instance of this happening:
 "Windows XP is supposed to recognize the Zen V as a MTP player automatically, but this didn’t happen on my Dell laptop. In this case, plug-and-play didn’t play very well. Creative support helped me fix this, but a non-technical user might find this process daunting." 
Maybe you should just contact Creative's Tech support as this person did.

Answer (score 0):

it could also depend on the version of windows media player, I would make sure both are at WMP 11, if not, update that.

Comment: The computer that works has WMP 9. I have tried WMP 9, 10 and 11 on the one that doesn't, with no change.